# Laravel 5 routes and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5, routes

I have a simple `routes.php` file, that looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors', 'prefix' => 'api'], function () {
  Route::post('users', 'Api\UsersController@save');
  Route::get('users/{userId}/leagues/', 'Api\UsersController@saveFavoriteLeague');
});
```

Once I put my application to server, I couldn't get to any of the routes executed. I was getting 404 exception.

I tried to make an obvious error in `routes.php` file, by putting `123` at the top of the file. Then I hit `mydomain.com/users/1/leagues`, and I was expecting error page, that there is a syntax error, but that didn't happen (still getting 404).
However, when adding something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
   return 'Hello';
});
```

and hitting home route `mydomain.com`, I was able to see at first syntax error, and then after fixing it, `Hello`.

I spent hours until I discovered that mod_rewrite, wasn't enabled on the remote server.

Can someone put more light on this?
Why my requests didn't reach `routes.php` (not even to show that there is an syntax error), but instead 404 page was returned. Why mod_rewrite made it to work? How could `/` reached the `route.php`, but `/users` e.g. didn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a request to the document root (`/` in your case), Apache will look for what is known as the `DirectoryIndex` - the default file that is loaded when such a request is made. Typically, this index file is `index.php`, `index.html`, or whetever is set by the server configuration or override file (`.htaccess`).

In your case, requesting `/` will serve up `index.php` by default - this is Laravel's bootstrap, and performs the initial steps required to boot up the application. Part of this includes fetching your routes and processing them.

However, when you request `/something` and `mod_rewrite` is not enabled (or your `.htaccess` file is not being read because `AllowOverride` is not set to `All`), Apache will not attempt to serve the `DirectoryIndex`, as it understands that a specific request is being made. Due to the fact that `/something` does not exist in your document root, a 404 will be thrown by Apache.

So, you need to make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled (enter `sudo a2enmod rewrite` into your terminal, or speak to your hosting provider), and ensure that your virtual host or default site configuration has set `AllowOverride All` for the document root directory.

You may also wish to try the following:

```bash
FallbackResource /index.php
```

This directive relies on `mod_dir` and not `mod_rewrite` to fallback to `index.php` instead of throwing a 404. This module is normally enabled by default.

Comment: so, if I got it right, in case 'mod_rewrite' is not enabled, apache will not serve 'index.php' and bootstrap 'routes.php' (when hitting anything diferent that '/')? i need to read more about mod_rewrite, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Indeed. Just remember that `routes.php` has nothing to do with `mod_rewrite`. They key here is `index.php`, which will only be served when requesting `/`.